# Not able to link against libxml2

Tags: linux, perl, apache, linker, libxml2

I need to install the perl module `XML-LibXML`. I have downloaded like below and tried to install. It says that not able to link `libxml2`. Then I have download libxml2 and installed then tried again but then also it did not succeed.
So shall I know how to link this installed libxml2.
Do I need to add the libxml2 installed directory(/install/others/lib) into the file "/etc/ld.so.conf" and Update the dynamic loader cache by running: ldconfig

```
bash-3.2$ wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/S/SH/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0019.tar.gz
bash-3.2$ tar zxvf XML-LibXML-2.0019.tar.gz
bash-3.2$ pwd
/install/others/XML-LibXML-2.0019

bash-3.2$ perl Makefile.PL LIBS='-L/install/others/lib' INC='-I/install/others/include'
enable native perl UTF8
Checking for ability to link against xml2...no
Checking for ability to link against libxml2...libxml2, zlib, and/or the Math library (-lm) have not been found.
Try setting LIBS and INC values on the command line
Or get libxml2 from
http://xmlsoft.org/
If you install via RPMs, make sure you also install the -devel
RPMs, as this is where the headers (.h files) are.

Also, you may try to run perl Makefile.PL with the DEBUG=1 parameter
to see the exact reason why the detection of libxml2 installation
failed or why Makefile.PL was not able to compile a test program.
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$ perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/install/others  LIBS='-L/install/others/lib' INC='-I/install/others/include'
enable native perl UTF8
Checking for ability to link against xml2...no
Checking for ability to link against libxml2...libxml2, zlib, and/or the Math library (-lm) have not been found.
Try setting LIBS and INC values on the command line
Or get libxml2 from
http://xmlsoft.org/
If you install via RPMs, make sure you also install the -devel
RPMs, as this is where the headers (.h files) are.

Also, you may try to run perl Makefile.PL with the DEBUG=1 parameter
to see the exact reason why the detection of libxml2 installation
failed or why Makefile.PL was not able to compile a test program.
bash-3.2$
```

Below is the DEBUG=1 added output

```
bash-3.2$ pwd
/install/others/XML-LibXML-1.31
bash-3.2$ perl Makefile.PL LIBS='-L/install/others/lib -lxml2 -lz -lm' INC='-I/install/others/include/libxml2' DEBUG=1
running xml2-config... xml2-config --version
failed
*** backticks call to 'xml2-config --version' failed at Makefile.PL line 212.
using fallback values for LIBS and INC
options:
  LIBS='-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lxml2 -lz -lm'
  INC='-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include'
If this is wrong, Re-run as:
  $ /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL LIBS='-L/path/to/lib' INC='-I/path/to/include'

looking for -lxml2... /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL 'INC=-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include' 'LIBS=-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lxml2 -lz -lm'
INC = -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include
LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lxml2 -lz -lm
Writing Makefile for Conftest
make test 'OTHERLDFLAGS=-lxml2'
cp Conftest.pm blib/lib/Conftest.pm
/usr/bin/perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/typemap  Conftest.xs > Conftest.xsc && mv Conftest.xsc Conftest.c
gcc -c  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gdbm -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic   -DVERSION=\"1\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"   Conftest.c
Conftest.xs:11: warning: return type defaults to âintâ
Running Mkbootstrap for Conftest ()
chmod 644 Conftest.bs
rm -f blib/arch/auto/Conftest/Conftest.so
gcc  -shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic Conftest.o -lxml2 -o blib/arch/auto/Conftest/Conftest.so       \
           -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lxml2 -lz -lm   \

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/Conftest/Conftest.so] Error 1
system call to 'make test 'OTHERLDFLAGS=-lxml2'' failed at Makefile.PL line 188.
no
libxml2 not found
Try setting LIBS and INC values on the command line
Or get libxml2 from
  http://www.libxml.org/
If you install via RPMs, make sure you also install the -devel
RPMs, as this is where the headers (.h files) are.
bash-3.2$
```

It is not looking for my local directory and it is looking for

```
INC = -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include
LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lxml2 -lz -lm
```

Note: I don't have root access and my Operation System is linux RedHat.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *If you install via RPMs, make sure you also install the -devel
RPMs, as this is where the headers (.h files) are.* So, have you installed the header files? If no, install them and retry the Perl module installation. If yes, where are they? (Also, why are you manually installing modules, and not using tools like cpanm together with local::lib?)

Comment: Have you tried the DEBUG=1 parameter as suggested in the error message?

Comment: @amon: he has no root access, so stock rpm installation won't work.

Answer (score 1):

you need the header files.

they are available as part of the libxml source distribution, e.g. [here](ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.1.tar.gz). extract the `libxml.../include` directory somewhere to your file system and include the directory in the `-I` flag of your make calls. the error messages also suggest that zlib and libm could not be found on your system. they might be located in non-standard `/usr/lib...` directories but will be present. include the found libs in the `-L` options of your make call.

Comment: -1 for not mentioning the downsides of compiling against uninstalled headers.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have root access you try to use perlbrew: http://perlbrew.pl/

Then you could install easily Alien::XML::LibXML (http://corion.net/perl-dev/Alien-XML-LibXML.html)

which installs libxml only for your local Perl.

After this the XML-LibXML should be installed successfully.

Steps:

1) install local perl with perlbrew to keep system perl clean

2) install Alien::XML::LibXML with cpanm from perlbrew

3) install XML-LibXML

Comment: no, install Alien:libxml don't let xml::libxml be installed, for it also look for libxml in default library path.

Answer (score 0):

install Alien::LibXML or download LibXML binary for your linux distribution,

`"export XMLPREFIX=$YOURLIBXMLPREFIX"`

$$YOURLIBXMLPREFIX/bin/xml2-config is OK.

then install XML::LibXML by cpan